# Mysql select data using advenced regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

Here are my example records

1. aasas jhdh 23 42 90-98 jhed
2. aasas jhdh 23 42 90-98 jhed
3. ghsd ahd 5 1999-2005 kjjef
4. kjdsj 3 4 2004-2013 dgdg
5. jhas 34 95-98 lhadadhj
6. jhas 34 84-93 lhadadhj

i want to select all where number before "-" is less than 100 or select all records where number between space and "-" consists of 2 digits. I don't know which way is easier.

Comment: Is it possible to have some data without `-` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f994f/2

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE name REGEXP '[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{1,2}-'
```